# Agora cloud recording with Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-cloud-recording

I want to record my voice call with agora cloud recording. I'm using a Postman collection provided by Agora, and I don't change anything except StorageConfig. I'm successful in getting resourceID and sid, but when I stop recording, I receive the error "Failed to find worker." Based on an agora document, they said for Google Clound the region parameter has no effect, whether it is set or not, so I'm setting it to 0. There's a list of solutions I've tried but have had no success with:

1. Change region
2. Both users have different UIDs, and the recording UID is different from them.
3. Access key and secret key is correct
   I don't know what I did wrong. Please help me. Thanks all.

```
{
    "resourceId": "nUwUbQf9Zg6tsgtLslGnDg0lk8RYaUE09pqOuSIgwfwi6-n9kITolzw3vvIFHMfm2VZsOrLd9fk9kMzos8Y_D-2Z2fFtUu_1BD2_pKJEZ-jTgXPe--K6Ua7TpSNY0pLd4zzyZV6iXCndqZvHmfsZloox0y-UZgs-r2_zBR2Gor05YCP0HuusWF8Kv1StAYabr1HJykw7RorDYnUIzzry6p6LRfvlq2zJVyVxvzVRVmoeMPYX-cVKyhNDuI2ct9a9aPdi8jCwDUzRbYimVVAnJBRYppTH012Xt6DnnMBkskJsbK0-CK3IaipQA9Gu2RmIJxSowuZbHspwA2lpwpzre-aNG6NlXk95hZgthOfNUVE",
    "sid": "edd35b65ec496e43aa502cad99bbdb27",
    "code": 404,
    "serverResponse": {
        "command": "StopCloudRecorder",
        "payload": {
            "message": "Failed to find worker."
        },
        "subscribeModeBitmask": 1,
        "vid": "1020399"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with another storage bucket, there can be a possibility of permissions on that existing bucket OR issue with the existing bucket.

Comment: Did you figure this I am stuck on this as well